# Android shrink large image size

Tags: android, image

If there is a image on my phone that I want to send up to a server thats 1mb or higher I want to take that image and shrink it to a smaller size without messing with original image in anyway. I know how to get a from the phone and I also know how to send it up to a server, I just need to know how to make the image smaller because large files higher than 1mb are giving me issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scale Bitmaps like so:

```
// Load in your bitmap here, I'll leave this detail up to you
Bitmap _bitmapPreScale = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, fieldValue); 

int oldWidth = _bitmapPreScale.getWidth();
int oldHeight = _bitmapPreScale.getHeight();
int newWidth = width;  // whatever your desired width and height are
int newHeight = height;

// calculate the scale
float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / oldWidth;
float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / oldHeight;

// create a matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// recreate the new Bitmap
Bitmap _bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(_bitmapPreScale, 0, 0,  oldWidth, oldHeight, matrix, true);
```

Comment: Is there a way to check the file size of the selected image. Like if file size is > 1mb or 1024kb do what you posted above, I have no problems with smaller file size images just those HD images. Thanks

Comment: Ok i think i can just use this File file = new File("infilename"); then call the file.length i think that will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

From your original Bitmap, you can use `createScaledBitmap(...)`
However, the difficulty might be to [open the large image in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037027/android-outofmemoryerror).