# can't Exit from my apk

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [force close the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489138/force-close-the-application) 
>   [Quitting an application - is that frowned upon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033914/quitting-an-application-is-that-frowned-upon)

Hi,
I have a lot of Activities and i want to exit the application - to close all activities and the services at once. i tried to  use this Process.killProcess( Process.myPid()) but that doesn't work , any tips?

Comment: This question comes up every single day.

Answer (score 0):

Use finish() and application will terminate.

Comment: Wrong. finish() closes activities, not applications.

Comment: finish() just close the current Activity and i have a few activities in the stuck,but what about all the other services that run on the background?