# View ddms heap size

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

In relation to this topic [`Android: OutofMemoryError....`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037027/android-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-with-no-reason-i-can-see)

How Can you see the heap size on ddms (Eclipse)? I can only track allocations and it doesn't show nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can try from code native heap allocation : `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`

Comment: Yes came across this but would prefer it in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

this shows max heap memory of device

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
```

this is for heap required by your app

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long maxMemory = rt.maxMemory();
```