# Android: Out of memory (VM budget...) on startup, on small percent of total installs

Tags: android

I get a clasical "VM budget excedees memory - out of memory" type error crash report from the Android Market.

I checked the app for memory leaks over and over again. This error happens on a very small percent of total application installs, around 1-2% and it always happens on start-up. The app loads some bitmaps from internal memory for each activity, but does not crash on most devices. I thought all applications had a guaranteed minimum stack size for bitmaps so this should work for every device. Min SDK is 7.

Any reason why ? Does this sound familiar to anyone ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037027/android-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-with-no-reason-i-can-see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue

Answer (score 0):

I had quite a similar problem, and my images were simply too big for some devices.

I have read that you have one image per `Activity` and I guess this happens when switching from one to another as the newly allocated `Drawable` cannot fit. What you could do, to save some memory, would be to unload the background image of the `Activities` that are not shown:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Drawable d = loadMyDrawableFromDisk();
    setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}

@Override
protected void onPause {
    setBackgroundDrawable(null);

    super.onPause();
}
```

It may help as the memory will be freed a few after `onPause()` is called, and not when the underlying `View` of your `Activity` will be unallocated by the system.