# Android ListView scroll delay due to ImageView drawing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I have a ListView that displays images loaded from the SD (JPGs previously taken with the camera). I use `imageView.setImageBitmap()` because the images are too large to display in the list and consume too much [(native) memory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3184850/933261), so I load a subsampled version with `inSampleSize`.

My problem is that the scroll delays before a new row is going to be displayed. Depending on the device the delay is more or less. Once you have reached the end the list the scroll becomes fluid.

Originally I performed the bitmap decoding in the ListAdapter getView():

```
BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2; //Subsample the original image
bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true; //The system can free the ¿native? memory allocated by the bitmap if needed
bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true; //Works in conjuction with inPurgeable
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bitmapOptions);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Then I tried to perform the decoding outside the UI thread. I executed an `AsyncTask` to decode all the bitmaps and cache it in memory. So in the getView() I only did `imageView.setImageBitmap()`. But I saw the same delay when scrolling. Using the method profiling tool in the DDMS I saw that the method `Canvas.native_drawBitmap()` was causing the delay, so the problem was not the bitmap decoding, but the ImageView drawing.

¿Any ideas to workaround this? ¿Why once a row have been displayed the first time there is no more delay when displaying this row? Maybe there is an ImageView displaying cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are scrolling the list, its loading dynamically in the **main thread**. At that time you are trying to do **setImageBitmap()** which is in turn trying to do in **main thread**. So whole task is slowed down.

So the solution is so **setImageBitmap()** in a **runOnUiThread(runnable)** or **Handler**. I faced this problem. This is the solution.

**EDIT :**

Do this,

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
   @Override    
   public void handleMessage(Message message) { 
        // do setImageBitmap(bitmap)    
   }    
};


new Thread() {  
   @Override    
   public void run() {  
        //get your bitmap   
        Message message = handler.obtainMessage(0, bitmap); 
        handler.sendMessage(message);   
   }
}.start();
```

Comment: So the goal is to avoid running the scroll in parallel with the `setImageBitmap()`. ¿Do you mean putting the `setImageBitmap()` in a `handler.postDelayed()`? Beacuse `runOnUiThread()` and `handler.post()` runs inmediatly on the UI thread, I have tested it and the effect is the same. With `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 400)` I dont see the delay (testing on a Wildfire) when scrolling but on the other side the delay loading the image is a bit high. I will continue testing.

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll your view, getView() method of your list adapter is called. This means, the more work you load to this method, the more it will delay.